# Codeigniter - Get fixed number of records from database and next time same no. of records after that

Tags: codeigniter

I am using infinite scroll. At first, I have to retrieve 5 records and on further scrolling down, I have to retrieve next 5 records. 
The query that I am using is as follows:

```
function profile1($uid) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('posts');
        $this->db->where('user-id', $uid);
        $this->db->limit('5');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        return $data->result();
    }
```

But it is giving me only first 5 records.
Can any body tell me how can I get next five records?
And same thing should be continued till the last record is printed.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should pass an another variable let say `$start` while requesting results.
so your function will be like

```
function profile1($uid,$start) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('posts');
        $this->db->where('user-id', $uid);
        $this->db->limit(5,$start);
        $data = $this->db->get();
        return $data->result();
    }
```

on your client side, keep incrementing this `$start` variable by 5, every time you make a call and pass that updated value in next call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the offset

To get 5 through 10

`$this->db->limit(5,5);`

To get 10 through 15

`$this->db->limit(5,10);`

For more information, see the `$this->db->limit();` section of the [Active Record Code Igniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: And suppose I have 100 posts, then what should be done? Isn't there any generalized way to do that?

Comment: If you have another question, then you should post another question

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience,I will change the question